# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - vsftpd problem. No connection. Connection refused

Tags: firewall, ftp, iptables, vsftpd, telnet

i have a problem with vsftpd server running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Here is the configuration:

ubuntu Server address - 192.168.5.100
router address - 192.168.5.1

```
roger/# grep -v "#" /etc/vsftpd.conf

listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=NO
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=NO
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=YES
idle_session_timeout=180
ftpd_banner=Welcome to rogers FTP s1rvices.
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

listen_port=16499
pasv_min_port=34720
pasv_max_port=34722
max_clients=1
max_per_ip=1
max_login_fails=4
tcp_wrappers=YES
seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

In my router (Fritzbox) the tcp ports 34720-34722 and 28001 (redirected to 16499) are opened and redirected to ubuntu servers address - 192.168.5.100.

I tried to connect about telnet local from the server:

```
# telnet localhost 16499
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I can´t find the way to resolve this problem. Help me plz.

Comment: try `netstat -atpn` to check it is listening through that port or different port...

Comment: `Roger:/# netstat -aptn
Aktive Internetverbindungen (Server und stehende Verbindungen)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      818/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      723/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      1573/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33141           0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      1312/rpc.mountd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      861/sshd`

Comment: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      936/cupsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37880           0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      1467/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5818            0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      1572/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49531           0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      945/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      818/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5918            0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      1572/Xtightvnc`

Comment: `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6018            0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      1572/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59111           0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      1312/rpc.mountd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33098           0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      1312/rpc.mountd
tcp        0      0 192.168.5.100:41005    xxx.xxx.xxx.84:443      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        1      0 192.168.5.100:44272    xxx.xxx.xxx.144:80       CLOSE_WAIT  2470/ubuntu-geoip-p
tcp        0      0 192.168.5.100:37481    xxx.xxx.xxx.143:443    TIME_WAIT   -`

Comment: `tcp        1      0 192.168.5.100:33336    xxx.xxx.xxx.144:80       CLOSE_WAIT  2588/ubuntu-geoip-p
tcp        0   2084 192.168.5.100:5901     xxx.xxx.xxx.168:24922    VERBUNDEN   1572/Xtightvnc
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::* LISTEN           818/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::* LISTEN           723/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 127.0.1.1:57268         :::* LISTEN           2414/java
tcp6       0      0 :::40916                :::* LISTEN           -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::* LISTEN           861/sshd`

Comment: `tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::* LISTEN           936/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::* LISTEN           1467/master
tcp6       0      0 :::8765                 :::* LISTEN           2414/java
tcp6       0      0 :::53661                :::* LISTEN           1312/rpc.mountd
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::* LISTEN           818/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::* LISTEN           -
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9666          :::* LISTEN           2414/java`

Comment: `tcp6       0      0 :::37194                :::* LISTEN           1312/rpc.mountd
tcp6       0      0 :::38250                :::* LISTEN           945/rpc.statd` Thats all - sorry, but i can´t post so long code columns.

Comment: try `netstat -atpn | grep "vsftpd" , did you try to find vsftpd before posting all those comments...?

Comment: no, i couldnt find "vsftpd". Trying: `service vsftpd start vsftpd start/running, process 10357 netstat -aptn | grep vsftpd` = nothing. Looks like the vsftpd stops immediately. Trying: `service vsftpd status vsftpd stop/waiting` ???

Comment: Ok, i removed the line `seccomp_sandbox=NO`.

Comment: Now the server runs. But i cannot connect in with FTP tool:`211 End
HELP SITE
214-The following commands are recognized.
ABOR ACCT ALLO APPE CDUP CWD DELE EPRT EPSV FEAT HELP LIST MDTM MKD
MODE NLST NOOP OPTS PASS PASV PORT PWD QUIT REIN REST RETR RMD RNFR
RNTO SITE SIZE SMNT STAT STOR STOU STRU SYST TYPE USER XCUP XCWD XMKD
XPWD XRMD
214 Help OK.
OPTS UTF8 ON
200 Always in UTF8 mode.
CWD /
250 Directory successfully changed.
Connect ok!
PWD
257 "/"
read directory
TYPE A
200 Switching to ASCII mode.`

Comment: `PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (192.168.5.100,131,16).
Server reports local IP -> Redirect to: xxx.xxx.xxx.172
Button 'break' acknowledged!
PORT 192,168,2,10,222,121
500 illegal PORT command.`

Comment: It would be nice if you edit your question and add the details there. Thank you

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I created new thread because it was hard to post here. Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/363216/ubuntu-12-04-vsftpd-problem-500-illegal-port-command